# Redshift Fill In Missing Rows in Table A from Table B

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Please help! I am not sure if Redshift has an issue or if it is just me.

Table A has the below data:

| Company_Name | Report_Type | Report_Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Sales | 123 |
| Apple | Employees | 804 |

Table B has the below data:

| Report_Number | Report_Type |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Sales |
| 804 | Employees |
| 654 | Inventory |
|  | Revenue |

I need the below output, i.e. to add missing report_types to Table A:

| Company_Name | Report_Type | Report_Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Sales | 123 |
| Apple | Employees | 804 |
| Apple | Inventory | 654 |
| Apple | Revenue |  |

Answer (score 1):

```
select t2.Company_Name , t1.Report_Type 
from (select distinct Report_Type from TableB) t1
cross join (select distinct Company_Name from tableA) t2
where not exists (select 1 from tableA t3 
                  where t3.Company_Name = t2.Company_Name 
                    and t3.Report_Type = t1.Report_Type
                  );
```